# Django run raw sql on existing queryset

Tags: sql, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django 3.2 and Django Rest Framework 3.12.2.
We have some custom OrderingFilters that override `OrderingFilter` and manipulate the received queryset.

We override the `get_ordering()` function of the `OrderingFilter`:

```
def get_ordering(self, request, queryset, view):
```

So far we used some of the django queryset abilities.
Now, I want to run a raw sql as part of the ordering process.
As far as I know, we can do something like -

```
MyModel.objects.raw("select * from my_model.....")
```

The problem is that as I see, we can only select from the whole table (my_model in that case) and not from the already prepared queryset.

What I would like to be able to do is something like -

```
query_set = MyModel.objects.filter(created_at='2023.03.07')
raw_query_set = query_set.raw("select * from query_set ...")
```

Is it possible in some way?

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding what you're trying to do but here is what I did in a similar situation:

You can get the actual SQL command from your queryset object like so:

```
query_set = MyModel.objects.filter(created_at='2023.03.07')
sql_command = str(queryset.query)
```

The `sql_command` variable holds the actual string that is going to be sent to your database. You can make additional changes to that string how you see fit. And then make a raw query using that `sql_command` string that you have updated.

This might not be what you want but it's the closest thing you're gonna get AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks @Ridape. That's a nice idea. I ended up doing something else. If I see that it doesn't work, I will try it.